# AutoHotKey ImageSearch

Tags: click, autohotkey, bots

So I am trying to make a game bot that will grind levels for me.
Currently, I have a bunch of these lines that are looped together:

```
ImageSearch, wherexis, whereyis, 895, 814, 1147, 947, C:\Users\AHK Stuff\startbattle.PNG
click %wherexis%,%whereyis%
sleep, 1400
ImageSearch, wherexis, whereyis, 934, 637, 1166, 797, C:\Users\AHK Stuff\attack.PNG
click %wherexis%,%whereyis%
sleep, 1400
```

However, sometimes my computer lags, and it won't load the image in the 1.4 seconds and it just skips to the next search and it messes up my bot. Is there a way that I can make it keep waiting for the image to appear rather than using sleep to wait for the page to load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `ErrorLevel` value.

It is detailed in the [documentation for ImageSearch](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm).

> ErrorLevel is set to 0 if the image was found in the specified region,
>   1 if it was not found, or 2 if there was a problem that prevented the
>   command from conducting the search (such as failure to open the image
>   file or a badly formatted option).

You could perform a loop with your `ImageSearch` command, check the `ErrorLevel` value, then use `break` if it is the value you are expecting.

Something like this:

```
Loop
{
    ImageSearch, wherexis, whereyis, 895, 814, 1147, 947, C:\Users\AHK Stuff\startbattle.PNG
    If ! ErrorLevel
    {
        Click %wherexis%,%whereyis%
        break
    }
}

Sleep, 1400
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! this worked, but the thing is if the image wasn't found it kept running the loop and ended up lagging the computer way more and it took an extra 4ish seconds. Any way to make the loop sleep for maybe 400 if the image wasn't found?

Comment: You could simply add `Sleep, 4000` to the last line of the loop because this will only run if `ErrorLevel` was set.